Rainbow-colored citations
Is it possible to have rainbow-colored citations ?
I saw this post Rainbow-colored text strings to get the rainbow color on strings, but I don't know how to adapt it to use it on all my citations (using \cite{something}).
I currently use citecolor=magenta in \hypersetup, and I want to use a rainbow color.
What should I do ?

Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be best if you could provide a minimal working example (MWE) that shows your setup including document class and packages you use as well as the concrete problems you encouter.

Hi ! I'm using overleaf (\documentclass{article}). I really don't know how to get a rainbow color instead of "magenta" in \hypersetup, because \gradient{HSB} (from the previous post) needs an argument.
As a second try, when I'm using \gradient{HSB} directly in the document (for instance gradient{HSB}{\cite{something}}{0,240,200}{240,240,200}, and it's not very efficient to do it on each citation), it's "\cite{something}" that will be rainbow-colored and not the result of the command \cite{something}

Please edit your question and add a minimal example starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document}. This helps others understand what your setup is like and what you want to achieve. Thank you very much!

The gradient-text package works best for plain text. If you want to use more complicate content, like macros, have a look at the solutions with tikz

Even if the rainbow colors has a very special meaning for the topic, I am unable to imagine a scenario where such colorism is a good idea in a text enough formal to have citations and references.
